# Change font used in the tab-bar of TreeStyleTab

Tags: firefox, 9.10, extension

Firefox 3.6.8 on Ubuntu 9.10; using TreeStyleTab 0.10.2010040201.

I use the tab-bar on the right, and I would like to see more of the tab names without widening the bar. The default font used is Sans, I believe; I would like to use something like condensed DejaVu Sans. I haven't found anything in the settings, nor in the `about:config` page, so I presume I can play some .css trick, but I don't know where to start.

How can I do this change?

Comment: @Javier: I'm sorry I rolled back your edit, but I believe it is important that this is an extension-related question; I'm looking for a specific answer hopefully by someone with the same extension installed; the generic answer by e.g. koushik, although correct, is not an actual answer to my question.

Answer (score 4):

Install Stylish extension:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108/

Then add this script:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

.tabbrowser-tabs .tab-text {
 font-size: 4mm !important;
 font-family: Condensed DejaVu Sans !important;
 font-weight: bold !important;
 color: #ffffff !important;
 text-shadow: 0 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,2),
        0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0,1) !important;
}
```

Change options to your linking.

It will look like this:

[image]

Comment: I already tried similar changes to userChrome.css; the TreeStyleTab extension does not follow tabbrowser-tabs styles; but thanks, anyway.

Comment: I use Tree Style Tabs and the picture above was taking from my screen. It works.

Comment: It works, thanks. I just added it to userChrome.css instead of installing Stylish.

Comment: And if you also want to increase the tab height, add this: http://pastebin.com/HqRFUjcv (the CSS class duplication is important to raise the specificity of this rule).

Answer (score 3):

You can tweak firefox UI fonts, colors etc by editing the userchrome.css file. The process is explained with a long list of snippets for "common" tweaks [here](http://www.linnhe2.free-online.co.uk/firefox/chrome.html). Or if u just want to tweak the font, you can check [this](http://gadgethubs.com/change-firefox-font-size-of-address-tab-and-status-bar/) is a short tutorial.

As per the official [mozilla howto](http://www.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html)

> Neither userChrome.css nor userContent.css exist by default. If
>   you want them, you create them in the
>   chrome subdirectory underneath the
>   user's profile directory.
>   userChrome.css controls CSS for the UI
>   chrome of the Mozilla application;
>   userContent.css controls CSS for
>   content inside windows.

Comment: So I guess I have to search in the `firefox/extensions/treestyletab@piro.sakura.ne.jp/chrome/treestyletab.jar` and locate the relevant `.css` file in order to find which setting might be the one and edit my `userChrome.css` (yes, I've created that one a long time ago). I was hoping to get a more specific answer, but thanks for answering anyway.